# What is following product? $ G = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} $.

Tags: group-theory, infinite-product

What is following product:
$$ G = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} $$
where $p$ is a prime and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is usual cyclic group of order $p^n$.

Obviously it is not isomorphic to the direct coproduct. It has both torsion end infinite-order elements and it has uncountable cardinality. So my first thought was unit circle or some kind of factorization of $p$-adic numbers. Is it some kind of metric completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ carries a natural topology: consider all $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ as discrete, then $G$ endowed with the product topology becomes a compact, totally disconnected space. The group operations are continuous, so this is a compact group, actually a *profinite* group, or even more precise, an abelian *pro-$p$ group*. The direct sum $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is a dense subgroup (consisting of the elements of $G$ with only finitely many entries $\ne 0$). Since the topology is also metric, $G$ can be viewed as metric completion of $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. The group of $p$-adic integers is a closed subgroup of $G$, namely the topological closure of the subgroup generated by $(1,1,\dots)$.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Can you elaborate on the last sentence that $p$-adic integers are exactly subgroup generated by $(1,1, \ldots)$? I don't quite see that.

Comment: Each $p$-adic integer can be viewed as an infinite sum $x=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kp^k$ with $0\le a_k\le p-1$. Inside $G$, $x$ is represented as the sequence $(a_0,a_0+a_1p,\dots)$, the $n$-th entry being $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kp^k$. Let $P$ be the set of all such sequences i.e. all $(u_0,\dots, u_i,\dots)\in G$ such that $u_{i-1}\equiv u_{i}\ (p^{i})$ for all $i$. Now, if you add the sequence $e=(1,1,\dots)$ sufficiently often to itself you arrive at any sequence of the form $(a_0,a_0+a_1p,\dots, y,y,y,\dots)$ where $y=\sum_{i=0}^na_ip^i$, $n$ and $a_i$ given. The set of these sequences is dense in $P$.